# Are there any visual graphs or tree hierarchy lists of meta policy posts?

Tags: support, policy

Similar to browsing a listing of current government or state laws (or Wikipedia for a [visual example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_policies_and_guidelines)), I would like to be able to see:

- The general/overview list of all policy topics;
- List of all relevant, linked, duplicate, closed posts to a specific policy topic;
- Which rulings/discussions are active, and which are outdated/obsolete/superseded by them.
- Topics on which there are currently no explicit policies;

Is there any such listing or a visualization on SE or external sites (advanced moderation helper third-party efforts)?

Using search or browsing tags doesn't allow to easily figure out which posts are duplicates of each other, which are still active or which are not final but intermediate discussion posts which did not lead to a policy change as can be found from just that post. In other words, it's hard to tell what the relationship or status of any given post is to any given policy.

Comment: There's the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), which links to other FAQ topic posts.

Comment: @RobertLongson it doesn't seem to be maintained often enough. I'm not sure if there were actually so few important changes to the policies on all SE sites, or that these 8-12 edits per year for the past 5 years were actually enough. In any case, it's a great starting point, but it's not comprehensive and it lists only the general rules, and specific SE sites don't have such meta posts outlining their own unique policies specific to them.

Comment: I'm pretty confident there is no such listing and given your own assumption that 8-12 edits of the official FAQ posts is not enough I doubt anyone in the community is willing to put more effort in to create and/or maintain such list.

Comment: Nope, but it dosen't sound like a bad idea. Heck, if someone would start it... I know some folks in the community might chip in,. for extra fun, there's site specific rules...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm wondering what the use case is? Why isn't the maintained FAQ list not suitable? What problem is being solved here? If this is an attempt to obtain an authoritative / consensus ruling on policies then I can predict that you will not find that. Then we first need consensus that we need consensus ...

Comment: Well, some people clearly prefer the structure. I mostly just moderate by the seat of my pants :D